# double.TryParse("Infinity",out dbl) return zero

Tags: c#-4.0

I am using `double.TryParse` method to parse my `string` to `double`. Here in some case `string` might be `NaN, Infinity, -Infinity`. While parsing this kind of text I want `double` value as `zero` instead of `double.Nan, double.Infinity`. So, `double.TryParse` has any option to do so or need to write a method to filter this.

Comment: *So, double.TryParse has any option to do so* [I feel bad for the people at Microsoft who write documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx)

Comment: You want to parse infinity to zero? what good can come out of it ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could simply double.TryParse(value == "Infinity" ? "0" : value) - question the input..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TryParse` has no option to behave the way you desire so you will have to code it yourself. Given that Infinity and NaN are not zero, it can be no surprise that none of the built in methods return zero for those inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it like that:

```
double value = 0;
double a = double.TryParse("YourString", out value) == true ? value  : 0;
```

If its not `double`, you will get 0 else the `value`.